# How can I change vfs FileURI dynamically in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I have this parameter with a path file:

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///Users/Desktop/test/in</parameter>
```

I need to change FileURI value dynamically, for example, using the value of a property that was set before. Something like that:

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">get-property('path')</parameter>
```

Or that:

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI" expression="get-property('path')"/>
```

How can I change the FileURI value for a property value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, with ESB 4.8.1, you can't change dynamically this parameter inside the mediation (this value is static).

Perhaps coul'd you  try to dynamically change this proxy definition at runtime :

- using admin services (ProxyServiceAdmin)
- or in java or javascript (with mc.getConfiguration(), you can access to synapse config)

An other solution would be to use a scheduled task :

- develop a custom task, see https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Writing+Tasks+Sample
- use file connector, see https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector#WorkingwiththeFileConnector-read

Answer (score 1):

In wso2esb4.8.1 Dynamically change our vfs endpoint.

[Dynamic Endpoint URL ref](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2torial-changing-vfs-endpoints-at-runtime)

Example:
We are getting filename by Property mediator "fname".

```
<property name="fname" expression="get-property('transport','FILE_NAME')"/>
```

We are getting "Path" dynamically by property mediator.

```
<property name="path" value="file:///D:/FileFolder/In/"/>
```

We are adding path and filename in "transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" property.

```
<property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="concat(get-property('path'),get-property('fname'))" scope="transport"/>

<send>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="vfs:file:///D:/Folder/In"/>
        </endpoint>
</send>
```

"transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" will replace send mediator vfs endpoint.

We can achieve Dynamic Endpoint.
we can move our file by Property mediator. We can change Property easily.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best approach is to store those values in database and load from a dataService, after that you can put and use them as properties.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using **combination of header mediator and default endpoint**. 
PATH is atual path eg. (D:/Test/Image) 
FILENAME is actual file ( testImage.png)

```
**<property expression="concat('vfs:file:///',$ctx:PATH,'/',$ctx:FILENAME)" name="localpath" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
 <header expression="get-property('localpath')" name="To" scope="default"/>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
 <call/>**
```

The default endpoint will look for the endpoint url from “To” transport header. Therefore, the endpoint can be constructed dynamically and set to “To” header.

FYI,
[ClickHere](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/WSO2-Developer-s-Guide/blob/master/Chapter11/API_vfs.xml)